# How to check the users and if the user is correct then marked the ordered section tick in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

when I check the Order button then, it should only update the status of  the user who has logged in into the system but in my case when x user click the order button then every different user who has not ordered  is marked as Ordered which I don't want

```
def orderList(request):
    order_qs = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    if request.method == "POST":
        status = request.POST.get("order")
        
        if (order_qs):
            Order.objects.update(ordered = status)
        
        else:
            Order.objects.update(ordered = False)
        

    order = Order.objects.get(user = request.user)
    context = {
        'order' : order,
    }

    return render(request, 'user_accounts/order_item.html',context)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when I check the Order button then, it should only update the status of the user who has logged in into the system but in my case when x user click the order button then every order marked as Ordered which I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you have to filter your `Order` objects by your authenticated user before updating.  Something like this:

```
def orderList(request):
    order_qs = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    if request.method == "POST":
        status = request.POST.get("order")
        
        if (order_qs):
            Order.objects.filter(customer=request.user).update(ordered = status)
        
        else:
            Order.objects.filter(customer=request.user).update(ordered = False)
        

    order = Order.objects.get(user = request.user)
    context = {
        'order' : order,
    }

    return render(request, 'user_accounts/order_item.html',context)
```

Here I am assuming that your Order objects are foreign keyed to your users somehow, with a possible field called `customer`.  Your database may be different.